# Как разбить построчно большой текст?

Tags: битрикс

`<BREAK />` Пробовал не работает.
Расскажите подробно, что надо сделать?

Comment: Построчно == постранично?
http://moy-1c-bitrix.blogspot.com/2012/11/blog-post.html
Расскажите подробно, что надо сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Пример текста (в качестве разделителя страниц - #BREAK#):

```
$TEXT = "test text, text
#BREAK#
test text, text
text, text
#BREAK#
test text";
```

Скрипт постраничного просмотра одного текста:

```
$aPages = explode("#BREAK#", $TEXT);
$res = new CDBResult;
$res->InitFromArray($aPages);
$res->NavStart(1);
if($res->IsNavPrint())
{
echo "<p>";
$res->NavPrint("Страницы");
echo "</p>";
}
while($page = $res->Fetch())
echo $page;
```